# How 'best' to return SQLite records by most recent date of report updates for submitted reports that are not closed

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, one with 'reports' and another with 'report updates'.  I want to show the most recent update date for reports that have not been closed, and the other 'Reports' information.

I have seen similar questions but am not sure if going that route is the best way. I had tried doing it with one table and I think I got it to work but two tables seems like the proper way. 
I am using SQLite with Python 3.7.

Table: [Reports]

```
+------------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+  
| ClientName       | Report_ID  | Submission_Date            | Closed_Date              |  
+------------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+  
| JoneBob          | 10010      | 2014-12-09 11:53:40.423    |                          |  
| TrumHar          | 10011      | 2014-11-09 11:53:40.423    |                          |  
| JoneBob          | 10012      | 2014-10-09 11:53:40.423    | 2014-10-20 04:00:00.000  |  
+------------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Table: [Report_Updates].

```
+------------------+----------------------------+
| Report_ID        | Follow_Up_Date             | 
+------------------+------------+---------------+
| 10010            | 2014-12-10 11:53:40.423    | 
| 10011            | 2014-11-11 11:53:40.423    |
| 10012            | 2014-10-14 11:53:40.423    |
| 10010            | 2014-12-12 11:53:40.423    | 
| 10011            | 2014-11-14 11:53:40.423    |
| 10012            | 2014-10-18 11:53:40.423    | 
| 10010            | 2014-12-13 11:53:40.423    | 
| 10011            | 2014-11-15 11:53:40.423    |
| 10012            | 2014-10-21 11:53:40.423    | 
+------------------+----------------------------+
```

Desired results:

```
+------------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+  
| ClientName       | Report_ID  | Submission _Date           | Follow_Up_Date           |  
+------------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+  
| JoneBob          | 10010      | 2014-12-09 11:53:40.423    | 2014-12-13 11:53:40.423  |
| TrumHar          | 10011      | 2014-11-09 11:53:40.423    | 2014-11-15 11:53:40.423  |
+------------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the maximum aggregation of `Follow_Up_Date` grouped by `ClientName` and `Report_ID` :

```
SELECT ClientName, r.Report_ID, 
       MIN(Submission_Date) AS Submission_Date, 
       MAX(Follow_Up_Date) AS Follow_Up_Date
  FROM Reports r
  JOIN Report_Updates ru
    ON ru.ClientName = r.ClientName    
 WHERE Closed_Date IS NULL   
 GROUP BY ClientName, Report_ID
```